# Qualtrics: make a page appear for 30 milliseconds

Tags: timing, milliseconds, qualtrics

I'm planning to run an experiment in Qualtrics that involves presenting a page to respondents fro 30 milliseconds.

The problem is that Qualtrics timing question does not allow to set the time for less than 1 second. i already contacted Qualtrics about this and they advised me to write my question here as it would be possible to do this with custom code. My programming skills are close to zero and thus I would really need some help with this. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to read the SO Question Checklist as Joe C suggested. Qualtrics Support shouldn't be referring people here for coding, they should refer them to their own help pages. That said, this is a very easy question, so here is the answer...add the following JavaScript to the first question on the page:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('NextButton').click(); }, 30);
});
```